# Is this use of "oppose" to express a contrast correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

I believe that movies have caused or created a false perception about a certain group of people. Instead, I believe that this group of people is exactly the opposite of how movies show them to be.  I want to express this in words, in a way something like this:

> **As opposed to what movies have shown them to be**, this group of people is very helpful and considerate.

Is the expression in bold correct? Is there a more natural way of saying it?

Comment: I would prefer e.g. "depict" instead of "show", because "show" can also mean "prove", but you are talking about works of fiction and not about documentary films, are you?

Comment: This is perfectly understandable and allowable. Stephen's "depicted" would be an improvement, but it's fine as is. Jonathan Garber's suggestion of "in contrast to" is also acceptable, but I see nothing wrong with your sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually better not to begin a sentence with "in opposition to. . ." or "as opposed to. . ." These are joining phrases, not ones to open a sentence, and they are more often used in weighing choices. A more standard way of conveying your meaning would be use of the word "contrast":

> In contrast to the way some movies depict them, [Group] has [Characteristic].

If you specifically wanted to use a form of "oppose" in the sentence, you could construct it like this:

> [Group] actually has [Characteristic X], as opposed to the movie depiction of them having [Characteristic Y].

Forms of "oppose" are more often used to indicate trade-offs in choices, however, not to illustrate a perceived difference in reality. A standard use might be like this:

> [Option X] will cost us [N Resources], as opposed to [Option Y], which will cost us [M Resources].